# String comparison always returns false

Tags: php

I'm uploading generic files with php, I read the first line of the uploaded file to validate (which is equals to `$line2`).

```
$line = file($target_file)[0];
$line2 = 'S01700006275696C642F697269732F6D61696E2E7372656343 ';

echo $line;
echo "<br>";
echo $line2;                                

if($line === $line2){
    echo "<br>true";
}else{
  echo "<br>false";}
```

Checking my outputs, I discovered theres an extra space in `$line` (Although there's no extra space on the file), So I added that extra space to $line2.

Problem is it always returns `false`. I have tried:

```
if($line == $line2)
```

as well as

```
if(strcmp($line,$line2)==0)
```

Obviously I tried removing the extra space from $line2

Comment: Copy and paste both lines here.

Comment: You can use trim() to remove the extra space

Comment: S01700006275696C642F697269732F6D61696E2E7372656343 
S01700006275696C642F697269732F6D61696E2E7372656343

Comment: trim() worked perfectly, thanks Pooya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$line = file($target_file)[0];
$line2 = 'S01700006275696C642F697269732F6D61696E2E7372656343 ';

echo $line;
echo "<br>";
echo $line2;                                

if(trim($line) === trim($line2)){
    echo "<br>true";
}else{
  echo "<br>false";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to detect if one string simply *contains* another, the correct test would be `if (strcmp($line,$line2) !== false)`.

If you want to test equality, ignoring whitespace, then use `if (trim($line) === trim($line2))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your additional whitespace is indeed a space?

In the manual entry for `file` ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)) it says:

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.

That's why your comparison fails.

Try reading the file like this:

```
$line = file($target_file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)[0];
```

That should work.